# Fast modular double exponential calculation?

Tags: algorithms

Given a modular double exponential problem:

$P^{a^b}$ % $M$ = ?  where

P = prime base, 
M is a composite number (we do not know its factorization),
b is of the special form (${2^k}-1$ for some k>1).

One of the ways to calculate it would be:

1. Calculate $P^a$ => $R_0$.
2. Caculate $(R_i)^a$ => $R_{i+1}$.
3. Repeat the Step 2. for b (or $2^k-1$) times.

But this process becomes slower with every single increase of k. Can we do any better than this given the special form of b ?

Comment: Could you add parentheses around your double-exponentiation to disambiguate?

Comment: Also, could you use LaTeX please? This isn't 4chan.

Comment: just edited. apologies.

Comment: This is close to factoring algorithm for arbitrary $b$ when $\phi(M)$ is smooth.

Comment: much thanks. I did not get how it is related to factoring and how a solution of this helps factoring or vice versa ? if possible could you elaborate and point to some resources ?.

Comment: If you can factor $M$ (and therefore compute $\phi(M)$ ), you can evaluate $c := a^b \mod \phi(M)$ by repeated squaring. Since $c$ is a manageable size, you can now evaluate $P^c \mod M$, also by repeated squaring. By Euler-Fermat, this result is equal to $P^{a^b} \mod M$.

Comment: much thanks.. But as the Q points out already '(we do not know its factorization)'.. otherwise we could have used CRT or the method as you pointed.

Comment: Anyone please ? Or do I take it, that no such method is known ?